# Direct file access vs. from localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, client, xmlhttprequest

Jquery ajax and direct ajax implementation done on my page. when I try to call ajax request from server it works fine when I direct double click on file, but when same file calls from localhost it gives me 302 error code.

I m not understanding why it gives me an error also same file not works in windows machines too but very well works on mac's & iphone simulator safari.

I have implemented soap request, just for your information.

So please let me know, it is problem with client or server side? how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome, $.ajax will not work when testing from Localhost. The error you will get is

> Origin null is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin

In Firefox and IE you can.

There are allot of posts on Stackoverflow discussing this issue. Here's one [Debugging Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Chrome/WebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753970/debugging-access-control-allow-origin-with-chrome-webkit)